# Can't fix my boot partition -- can I restore Ubuntu from a copy (not properly imaged) of my partition?

Tags: ubuntu, partition, backup

On my old Ubuntu system (the one I'm trying to restore to) I had a boot partition `/dev/sda1`, my main OS partition `/dev/sda2`, and a swap partition `/dev/sda3`. I mistakenly formatted over `/dev/sda1` turning it into a FAT32 fs.

The first thing I did was use testdisk to make sure my file system was intact (which it was), so I copied it to an external hard disk -- meaning I did `cp -r /dev/sda2 /path/to/external/backup`. Is it possible to use my live CD to get a fresh install with a proper boot partition and then do `mount /path/to/external/backup some/proper/mount/point` then write in `/etc/fstab` something so that I can boot into it? What would the actual process be exactly?

I already tried 2 or maybe 3 different ways to fix my grub partition so I can boot into the /dev/sda2 that's still on my laptop SSD, but I'm going on week 3 of trying to fix that issue and don't have time to mess with it any more.

Comment: `cp -r` isn't the best way to make a backup. If using `cp` at least use `cp -a`, but a filesystem archiver like `fsarchiver` might suit you better.

Comment: If your OS is still on /dev/sda2, it should be doable. Is it? Can you post `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda`?

Comment: @TNW 
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sda: 256.1 GB, 256060514304 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 31130 cylinders, total 500118192 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x4b904150

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1   500118191   250059095+  ee  GPT

Comment: @TNW, here's a [screenshot](http://imgur.com/a/NyVbT) showing that testdisk recognizes the partition and even lets me open the files of my old file system.

Answer (score 0):

Fixing this should be possible, and it roughly resembles Arch Linux installation process (disclaimer: I might be mistaken about some steps, please comment if you're in trouble).

First of all, boot with your live CD/DVD/USB. Then, mount your partition (everything as root!):

```
mkdir /mnt/ubuntu
mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/ubuntu
```

Then, backup all you might need from your /dev/sda1 and reformat it for something GRUB-suitable - let's say that ext3 will do:

```
mkfs.ext3 /dev/sda1
```

Then mount it within your system location, then bind the stuff that usually gets filled during boot process:

```
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/ubuntu/boot
mount -o bind /dev /mnt/ubuntu/dev
mount -o bind /dev/pts /mnt/ubuntu/dev/pts
mount -o bind /proc /mnt/ubuntu/proc
mount -o bind /sys /mnt/ubuntu/sys
```

Finally, jump into your old Ubuntu:

```
chroot /mnt/ubuntu
```

You should now become root on your old Ubuntu, assuming everything gone well. You'll basically have to reinstall grub and kernel (assuming grub2 and pkg names as in Debian):

```
aptitude install grub2 linux
```

Install grub on your HDD:

```
grub-install /dev/sda
```

Then generate the config:

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Review the config, and if it looks okay you should be good to go! Reboot and try if it works.

Comment: I'm good with these instructions up until the second to last step:

root@ubuntu:/# grub-install /dev/sda   -->   Installing for i386-pc platform.   -->   grub-install: warning: this GPT partition label contains no BIOS Boot Partition; embedding won't be possible.   --> 
  grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..   -->     
grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists.

Comment: After looking into the error mentioned above, I tried resizing /dev/sda1 so that there is 50MB of free space in front of this partition...no success with that.

Comment: @aweeeezy [Look there.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#GUID_Partition_Table_.28GPT.29_specific_instructions) If you create that 1MB partition in the free space you made, and then set it's type to "BIOS Boot", you should be able to install grub alright.